# How to upload File from ajax to django backend?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Any ideia how to upload File (.pdf) from ajax to django backend ?

```
customerForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
e.preventDefault()
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '',
    data: {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
        'identity_type': $('#id_identity_type').val(),
        'identity_number': $('#id_identity_number').val(),
        'file': $('#id_file').val()
    },
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('SUCCESS')
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Thank You

Comment: For one thing, you need a value for the URL, not an empty string.

Comment: Note that from the point of view of the JavaScript, it doesn't matter that the server is written with Django. The JavaScript only knows how to make an HTTP request and doesn't care what language actually implements it.

Comment: Also, be sure that you set the correct headers in the request, especially `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways but Here's a link it's simple I think

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g3h1OC3S5Lo

He/She explains how to upload file using **ajax**.